# grafana graph is not showing

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I am new in influxdb and grafana .On grafana dashboard I am getting influxdb response with metrics query but grafana graph is not showing with that data
Data I got from influxdb is

{"results":[{"series":[{"name":"cpu_load_short","columns":["time","value"],"values":[["2016-06-17T06
:23:39.3855934Z",0.64],["2016-06-17T07:10:54.1543272Z",0.64],["2016-06-17T08:21:43.8362874Z",0.64],["2016-06-17T08
:30:54.2708891Z",0.64],["2016-06-17T08:38:06.8087172Z",0.64],["2016-06-17T08:38:40.659661Z",0.64],["2016-06-17T08
:38:46.0169674Z",0.64],["2016-06-17T08:38:57.2826142Z",0.64],["2016-06-20T08:44:40.7810414Z",0.64]]}
]}]}